# VS 2017: How can I change the "Convert to full property" template?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, coding-style, intellisense

How can I change the "Convert to full property" template to not prefix private fields with underscore?

Right now it does this...
[image]
...But I don't want to have underscore prefixes on my fields.

I also don't want them to be in a single line if it's a full property.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 4):

You can change that in the options of Visual Studio.

In the options (menu `Tools > Options...`) navigate to

```
Text Editor > C# > Code Style > Naming
```

Click the button  <kbd>Manage styles</kbd>  and define your own style (e.g. "camelCase").
Under "Private or Internal Field" choose your desired style.

The templates will use these style settings.

Btw.: the underscore is there to differentiate the fields from the local variables and method parameters. In VB the prefix "m_" is often used for fields. "m" stands for "member", (e.g. `m_myField`).

Comment: I always use the underscore to denote private class fields, makes it nice to know where a variable came from and all come up in intellisense when I hit that key since it seems my memory is shorter than the distance between the field declaration and scrolling to the method.

Comment: Thanks! The field name now doesn't have underscore prefix.
How do I change the template to be in multiple lines instead of inline getter and setter?

Comment: You can create your own code snipptes. VS has a code snippet manager. There are also various extensions for VS for editing and managing code snippets. And there is also the "Use block body for accessors" refactoring.